# Date of birth change

Tags: airports, london, advance-passenger-information

How can I change the date of birth after checking in and the phone lines are closed please can someone help ryanir

Answer (score 5):

**You probably don't need to change it.** Passport information like date of birth is generally only locked in when you actually check in at the airport and present ID.

The main exceptions are:

- If the incorrect age means you bought the wrong kind of ticket (infant/child/adult)
- Some countries like the US that demand accurate passenger information in advance (APIS), but AFAIK none of Ryanair's destinations do

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Ryanair Help Centre](https://helpcentre.ryanair.com/hc/en-ie/articles/9626619854865-I-have-checked-in-can-I-change-my-travel-documents) once you have checked in, you cannot change your travel documents online.

Try contacting their [chat team](https://helpcentre.ryanair.com/hc/en-ie/categories/9945335083025-Contact-Us).